# Why is the Pi 4 SOC documentation hidden?

Tags: pi-4, bare-metal

I was interested in doing some bare metal development with the PI 4 but there are substantial aspects of the SOC which are not publicly documented, particularly in relation to network/WIFI/GPU.

Why is this? What advantage exists in keeping this information hidden? Also: how can the Pi Foundation develop for this SOC without the information? Or does the PI Foundation own it themselves?

Comment: Perhaps try Pico, which is 99% open hardware and software.

Comment: I was also considering the Beagle Bone Black.

Comment: Yes, BBB is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is  "hidden". The SOC is well documented although the Video Core is not public without an NDA.

The other items on the Pi may not have full details published because documentation takes a major effort and is expensive. There is no reason for the Foundation to fund this to meet its educational objectives.

I am sure that if you were prepared to fund it i.e. pay for a couple of extra employees the Foundation may be willing.

Comment: This is a nonsense response,  the engineering process requires detailed documentation of everything.